# Is flipping a vector x the same as x[-n]?

Tags: matlab, convolution

I was intending to use the following convolution property in my Matlab code.
$$y[-n]=x[-n]*h[n]=x[n]*h[-n]$$

However, I am noticing that the results seems not the expected ones, for example let have

```
x = [ 1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     1]

h = [1     1     0   0     1     0     1]
```

I am seeing that implementing left hand of above equation in Matlab with [flip](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) like

$$x[-n]*h[n] = \texttt{conv}(flip(x),h) $$

```
conv(flip(x),h)  =  1     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0      1     1     0     0     1     0     2     1     0     0     1     0     1
```

However, doing right hand section
$$x[n]*h[-n] = \texttt{conv}(x,flip(h)) $$
results into

```
conv(x,flip(h)) = 1     0     1     0     0     1     2     0     1     0     0     1     1   0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1
```

Hence I wonder whether flip is the correct way to implement time inversion in matlab, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you find this property?

Comment: @AhsanYousaf There is no proof there. Just because a slide says it’s true doesn’t make it so. This property makes no sense. Say *h* is the Dirac delta. After time reversal it is still the Dirac delta. The property is saying that flipping *x* and this Dirac delta will yield the same convolution result as not flipping either. This is impossible unless *x* is symmetric around 0.

Comment: No, the property doesn't hold in general, even if it is written on some slide ...

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Thx, you beat me to it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct to use `Flip` for time reversal, just as long as you take into account the shift, which leads to a shifted result. So the output will not have the first element be at *n*=0, but at some other value.

However, you are trying to prove a false property. No LTI system can reverse its input.
If this property were true, then reversing the impulse response of a system would yield a LTI system that reversed its input.

Moreover, if this property were true, then reversing both the signal and the impulse response would lead to the same result, which is impossible. The actual result would be reversed also:

$$y[n] = x[n]*h[n] \implies y[-n] = x[-n]*h[-n]$$

And indeed,

```
y1 = conv(x,h);
y2 = flip(conv(flip(x),flip(h)));
isequal(y1,y2)
```

will be true.

Comment: Thanks Cris for clarifying this, I should have tried to prove this on paper apart from trying to implementing it. Blind trust has a cost :)

Answer (score 1):

Before using any command in any programming language please actually understand what it does!

Consider the following discrete time sequence:

$$x[n] = [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,2]$$

which looks like this if we use zero-based indexing (which Matlab does not):

[image: x[n]]

and if we also place our axis of symmetry for the time reversal at $n=0$ then we have:

[image: x[-n]]

Now do you see the problem? The problem is:

The `flip` function is not implementing this! Rather it is doing the following (mind the one-based indexing):

[image: mat_x]

and the flip makes it:

[image: flip_x]

Edit: The property mentioned does not hold in general because flipping one function and performing convolution is just correlation and correlation in general is NOT the time reversal of convolution. Also see the reasons stated by @Cris Luengo in the comments.

Comment: So `Flip` is time-reversal and a shift. The result of the convolution will be shifted too. But it should not be totally different from the expected result. Which it is, because this property is false.

Comment: Thanks @Ahsan I was aware of `flip` time-reversal but I was overlooking the shift aspect of it

Comment: @ndarkness Cris is right! In general, this property is not true! I will update my answer to reflect that, soon.